# amazon pinpoint integration with webapp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

Have cognito setup and working and I'm using pinpoint for analytics to track user sign-ups, sign-ins. etc. the problem is I have setup pinpoint according to this doc (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html) and have connected it to the app client in cognito but I am not getting any data in pinpoint when I sign up a new user etc. Specifically when I create a new user in my webapp I confirm that the new user has indeed been created in cognito and then check pinpoint and pinpoint shows zero users have signed up.

Answer (score 0):

What SDKs are you exactly using to interact with the services? If you are using any of the Javascript SDKs, you need to populate the AnalyticsMetadata https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/apis/cognito-idp-2016-04-18.normal.json#L2344 in the particular requests since the Javascript AWS frameworkds don't provide this functionality on your behalf (similar to the Android and iOS SDKs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, I think I was making the assumption that by connecting cognito to pinpoint that there would be no additional configuration required. It looks like i'll have to add code to my front end to inform pinpoint of user activity? Also, yes I am using javascript for my front end and C# for back end.

Comment: Also do you have any idea where I could find examples of sending 'sign-in', 'sign-out', 'login', etc. request to pinpoint for logging with javascript? I have been searching around but can't seem to find any examples. I only see examples with IOS and Android.